# App Engine HTTP Status Code message

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-status-code-400

I found an inconsistency between Java's `dev_appserver` and the live App Engine server.

On my local development server I have a Servlet which returns:

```
return response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Please log in to comment");
```

When I access the page I get back a Status Code message in the header which is:

```
Status Code:400 Please log in to comment
```

The issue comes when I deploy this to App Engine. When accessing that same servlet I get this "Bad Request" instead of "Please log in to comment":

```
Status Code:400 Bad Request
```

The `Please log in to comment` Status Code message appears in the content HTML, but not in the header as it does in the development environment.

Why is this?

**Edit**

Here's the `curl -vvvv` traces for both dev_appserver and production:

dev_appserver curl trace:

```
> POST /add-comment HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 9
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>         
< HTTP/1.1 400 Please log in to comment
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Length: 1406
< Server: Jetty(6.1.x)
```

Production curl trace:

```
> POST /add-comment HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
> Host: www.xxx.org
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 9
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 14:04:26 GMT
< Server: Google Frontend
< Cache-Control: private
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Can you add curl -vvvv trace for the two calls, devappserver and production ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the prod system is the correct implementation. The javadocs for `sendError()` say:

> Sends an error response to the client using the specified status. **The
>   server defaults to creating the response to look like an
>   HTML-formatted server error page containing the specified message**,
>   setting the content type to "text/html", leaving cookies and other
>   headers unmodified. If an error-page declaration has been made for the
>   web application corresponding to the status code passed in, it will be
>   served back in preference to the suggested msg parameter.
>
> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an
>   IllegalStateException. After using this method, the response should be
>   considered to be committed and should not be written to.

I highlighted a part. This says it just returns a html page with the message when possible. It doesn't say it uses it in the HTTP Status code (which I personally haven't seen anywhere as well :()

Comment: Interesting. It seems though you're right. Nothing says anything about the Status Code message. Jetty (dev_appserver) seems to be showing it as an HTTP Status Message, but others may not. I wonder if there's a way to force it in the App Engine environment - I guess being able to set your own Status message in the header should be something people can do.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't specifically a problem with `sendError`. The `setStatus` method will behave the same way. Under normal Java, both `sendError` and `setStatus` do set the status description. The issue is that the production App Engine server always sets the status description to the standard description for each code.